# What are different kinds of shops based on the size, structure and location?

Tags: terminology, vocabulary

In my native language there are so many words to mean different kinds of shops based on the size, structure and location.

I'm not talking about the types like grocery shop, barber shop, meat shop, book shop, etc. I'm talking about kinds of shops like below:

- Mall: Meaning a big shop or a complex with many shops
- Store: Meaning a small shop.
- Booth shop: Meaning a very small shop, may be temporary built one room shop.

I don't know the words otherwise I can explain clearly and I'm looking for those words. For example what do you call a shop which is setup on the road side which has no roof?

Comment: If it has wheels, it's sometimes called a _vendor's cart_. But it's not clear what you're asking for here – just that one kind of shop, or a more comprehensive list?

Comment: J.R., I'm looking for more comprehensive list

Comment: It's always hard to provide a comprehensive list, but some words I can think of are *market, boutique, bazaar, outlet, outlet mall, studio, warehouse, mart, convenience store, stand,* and *kiosk*. Time and space prevent me from listing the definitions and nuances of each, but a good online dictionary like [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/market) provides plenty of definitions, plus additional synonyms for even more candidate words.

Comment: In addition to mall, shop and store, there's Stall, Boutique, Kiosk and Plaza, Market, Mart, Outlet, Shopping center, Showroom,  and Stand.  And then you can add *super* to alot of those: supermarket, superstore, supermart etc.

Comment: @J.R. WOW! What a good dictionary for this purpose. Thanks a lot! I needed it.

Comment: @Jim You have a Very Interesting use of Certain Capital Letters that seems more relevant to Days Gone By then to Today.

Comment: @tchrist- Yeah, I don't know how I got that, my fingers seem to do it by themselves and I always have to go back and review and change things.  Maybe it's a "*past life experience intruding on present time.*" ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the list J.R., Another Thanks for providing Wordnik url. I looked at it, it seems like wonderful dictionary. Never heard of it.

Answer (score 1):

A little shop set up by the road side (and roofless, or with a tent-style roof, or in a cart) is known as a **street vendor**. They are very common in large cities. I found a good link defining this: [What Is a Street Vendor?](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-a-street-vendor.htm). Quoted from this source:

> Street vendors are businesspeople who sell their wares in the open air
>   rather than in a shop or store. In many cases, the vendor either has a
>   small stand that can be secured when not in operation, or makes use of
>   a cart that can be removed from the street at the end of the business
>   day. Sometimes referred to as a peddler, the street vendor is commonly
>   found in metropolitan areas, outdoor conventions and events, and
>   sometimes at public beaches.